# How can get the objects value in Symfony Controller

Tags: php, symfony, object

How can get the amounts value from vouchers Entity?

I want to add a condition for the amount, if the amount is empty then don't insert the values on the database.

getVouchers() Entity.

```
["vouchers":"AppBundle\Entity\Participant":private]=>
  object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#985 (1) {
    ["elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=>
    array(7) {
      [0]=>
      object(AppBundle\Entity\Product)#993 (9) {
        ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\Product":private]=>
        NULL
        ["description":"AppBundle\Entity\Product":private]=>
        NULL
        ["amount":"AppBundle\Entity\Product":private]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["alreadyWon":"AppBundle\Entity\Product":private]=>
        NULL
        ["value":"AppBundle\Entity\Product":private]=>
        string(4) "2,50"
        ["discountPrice":"AppBundle\Entity\Product":private]=>
        NULL
        ["image":"AppBundle\Entity\Product":private]=>
        NULL
        ["participant":"AppBundle\Entity\Product":private]=>
        *RECURSION*
        ["participant_voucher":"AppBundle\Entity\Product":private]=>
        NULL
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your getVouchers() contains an array collection.

so why don't you try like this.....

```
foreach(getVouchers() as $voucher){
    if (empty($voucher->getAmount())) {
        //your logic
    }else{
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: getAmount() is not a Entity.

Comment: Uh? so what ? Your comment makes no sense... Anyway could you be more specific about which value you do not want to insert into database ? Is it just the amount value or the entire Voucher entity ?